# Finding Eigenvalue for cubic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm learning finding eigenvalues. I learned how to find simplistic eigenvalues for $3\times3$ matrix.
By using below way. With this way I can only solve if I have simple determinant equation, like quadratic.

> Find eigenvalues of $\lambda_i$, which are roots of $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. $$\det(A-\lambda I)=\begin{vmatrix} 4 & 6 & 10 \\ 3 & 10 & 13 \\ -2 & -6 & -8\end{vmatrix} - \lambda \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{vmatrix}$$

But for some of the matrices are big numbers and  becoming cubic equation which won't have integer numbers as eigenvalues.  I guess I need to simplify the matrix before somehow. Which I cannot find.

Can you please guide me how can I handle if matrices are not simple?

Any references or tutorials are appreciated.

I watched below video tutorial but author is using simple matrix in example:
[Eigenvalue and Eigenvector Computations Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHOsd2PhkqE)

Comment: I expect you're just meant to take the determinant of the whole thing. It simplifies rather nicely in the end :)

Comment: In your display, you have written $\det(A-\lambda I)$ on the left, but you have written $\det A-\lambda\det I$ on the right. They are not the same thing. You want to subtract $\lambda I$ from $A$ first, then take determinants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only at school that Eigenvalues are integer numbers ;-)

For the 3x3 case, you have the option of using the Cardano-Tartaglia formulas to solve the third degree equation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function. They involve complex numbers.

Fourth degree can also be addressed by explicit formulas. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation

As induced by Evariste Galois at the age of 17, there is no similar formula for degree 5 and above.

In practice, numerical methods are used. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm.

Also have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#3.C3.973_matrices.

Comment: thank you for your answer! :) for 3x3 I've just found http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-a-Cubic-Equation I guess its the same thing as in Wiki, right?

I'm not quite sure, but I heard before doing determinant I should do some operation on existing matrix to make it simpler and solve it, how is this true? Thank you!

Comment: In the general case there is no simplification, but check my last pointer.